# Rxjs Subscribe been called twice

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, rxjs5

None of similar asked questions helped me, so here goes my problem
I am using rxjs subscribe method, but it is been fired twice and i would like it to be called once.
Here is my code:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { Validators, FormBuilder, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
import { CadastrarUsuarioPage } from '../cadastrar-usuario/cadastrar-usuario';
import { FirebaseProvider} from '../../providers/firebase/firebase';
import { AngularFireOfflineDatabase, AfoListObservable, AfoObjectObservable } from 'angularfire2-offline/database';
import { HomePage } from '../home/home';
@Component({  
  selector: 'page-login',
  templateUrl: 'login.html',
})
export class LoginPage {
  private form: FormGroup;
  private usuario: string;
  private senha: string;
  public afoList: AfoListObservable<any[]>;  
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,
              public navParams: NavParams,
              private statusBar: StatusBar,
              private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
              private afoDatabase: AngularFireOfflineDatabase
            ) {
                this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
                  usuario: ['', Validators.required],
                  senha: ['', Validators.required]
                });
  }

  ionViewDidLoad()
  {
    this.statusBar.hide(); 
  }

  entrar()
  {
    let usuario_senha = this.usuario + "_" + this.senha;
    this.afoDatabase.list('usuarios/', {query: {
      orderByChild: 'usuario_senha',
      equalTo: usuario_senha
    }}).take(1).subscribe((x) => {
      if(x.length == 1)
      {
        console.log("true");
      }
      else
      {
        console.log("false");
    }},
    error =>{
        console.error("Error in subscribe: ", error.message);
    },
    () =>{
      console.log("done");
      });
  }

  abrirCadastrarUsuario()
  {
    this.navCtrl.push(CadastrarUsuarioPage);
  }
}
```

and it prints “false”/“true” and “done” 2x each time it is called.

**--UPDATE --**
as ordered, the entire code, it is been called inside a button click

**-- UPDATE --** 
The component from where it is been called from

```
<ion-content padding class="content">
    <ion-grid>
      <form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="entrar()">
        <ion-row style="height:50px;margin-top:30px" align-items-center>
          <ion-col col-12 text-center class="login-title">
            Login Offline
          </ion-col>
        </ion-row>
        <ion-row>
          <ion-col col-12>
            <ion-list>
              <ion-item class="no-background border-top-transparent">
                <ion-label color="branco" floating>Usuário</ion-label>
                <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="usuario" formControlName="usuario"></ion-input>
              </ion-item>
            </ion-list>
            <ion-list>
              <ion-item class="no-background border-top-transparent">
                <ion-label color="branco" floating>Senha</ion-label>
                <ion-input type="password" [(ngModel)]="senha" formControlName="senha"></ion-input>
              </ion-item>
            </ion-list>
          </ion-col>
        </ion-row>
        <ion-row>
          <ion-col col-12>
            <button type="submit" color="branco" style="height:50px" (click)="entrar()" ion-button block outline round>Entrar</button>
          </ion-col>
        </ion-row>
      </form>
    </ion-grid>
    <div class="cadastrar"><p class="cadastrar-texto" (click)="abrirCadastrarUsuario()">Cadastre-se</p></div>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: Where is this code located? Who/what calls it?

Comment: Can you share the whole component so we can see where/how this code i called?

Comment: as ordered, updated!

Comment: Show us the template of the component, since that's where it's being called from.

Comment: `entrar()` is not called anywhere... And I have a feeling it is called in some `*ngIf` or directly in `{{ entrar() }}`

Comment: Done! Included the component.

Comment: OK. Now just use `Ctrl-F entrar` on your template, and see that it's called twice: once in the (click) of the submit button, and once in the (ngSubmit) of the form.

Comment: Holy moly, you guys are AWESOME. Realy thank you, I would never have figured it out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `entrar()` function is called twice because of `ngSubmit` here:

`<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="entrar()">`

and button's type submit in here:

`<button type="submit" color="branco" style="height:50px" (click)="entrar()" ion-button block outline round>Entrar</button>`

Basically on button's click event you are submitting the form which indirectly call the `entrat()` function from `(ngSubmit)` while on the other hand this function is also directly called from button's click `(click)="entrar()"`